# Start and stop tasks in IHostedService

Tags: c#, task, asp.net5, ihostedservice

I've created an ASP.NET core API but I can't figure out how to implement the IHostedService correctly.
I have several "worker" classes that need to run as background processes so I'm using the IHostedService to start all tasks async.

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddHostedService<BackgroundService>();
```

BackgroundService.cs:

```
public class BackgroundService: IHostedService
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return RunTasks (cts.Token);
    }

    private List<IWorker> workersToRun = new List<IWorker>();
    private Task RunTasks(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            Worker1 w1 = new Worker1(); //Implements IWorker
            workersToRun.Add(Task.Run(() => w1.DoWork(cancellationToken)));
            
            Worker1 w2 = new Worker2(); //Implements IWorker
            workersToRun.Add(Task.Run(() => w2.DoWork(cancellationToken)));

            Task.WhenAll(workersToRun.ToArray());
            
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
        finally
        {
            //Wait for all started workers/tasks to complete ??????
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        cts.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Worker.cs

```
public interface IWorker
{
    Task DoWork(CancelationToken token)
}

public class Worker1 : IWorker
{
    public Task DoWork(CancelationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return Task.Delay(1000);
            //Do some random stuff in the background
        }
        
        //cleanup
    }
}

public class Worker2 : IWorker
{
    public async Task DoWork(CancelationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000); 
            //Do some random async stuff in the background
        }
        
        //cleanup
    }
}
```

The worker classes seem to work (based on the logs) but the cancelationToken does not so the cleanup code is never executed (it seems).
How can I correctly cancel all running tasks and wait for them to complete in the StopAsync method?

(all code above is simplified, it actually contains di and error handling but that is not relevant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems with your code.

1. You are not passing the cancellation token to `Task.Delay()`, and it's a good bet that your workers will be stuck in this method for quite a while. (Aside, I know you're likely doing that delay so you can test cancellation, but as coded it interferes with your test).
2. The token given by `cts.Token` is not the same one as the `cancellationToken` parameter for the `BackgroundService` (most likely).
3. You're doing `Task.WhenAll()` in the `StartAsync`, which, when you apply `await` to it, will block the start until all of the tasks actually complete. I don't think that's what you want.
4. Cancellation is cooperative so you need to check for cancellation right after that delay. When you remove the delay "for real", be sure to add the cancellation checks in whatever will implement `//Do some random async stuff in the background`, including passing the token down your async stack.
5. Finally, I recommend doing async/await "all the way down".

Here is some code that removes the issues above.

```
public class BackgroundService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public BackgroundService(CancellationTokenSource cts) => this.cts = cts;

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => await RunTasks (cancellationToken);

    private List<Task> workersToRun = new List<Task>();

    private async Task RunTasks(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            // tasks are started immediately below
            var w1 = new Worker1();
            workersToRun.Add(Task.Run(async () => await w1.DoWork(cancellationToken)));
        
            var w2 = new Worker2();
            workersToRun.Add(Task.Run(async () => await w2.DoWork(cancellationToken)));

            // no Task.WhenAll() here. If you do that, RunTasks() will be blocked until they complete!
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Program.WriteLog(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // skip cancellation if we don't need it
        if (workersToRun.All(x => x.IsCompleted))
            return;

        try
        {
            Program.WriteLog("Call Cancel()");
            cts.Cancel();
        }
        finally
        {
            // wait for all started workers/tasks to complete
            Program.WriteLog("WhenAll()");
            await Task.WhenAll(workersToRun);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and one of the workers,

```
public class Worker1 : IWorker
{
    public async Task DoWork(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000, token);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                Program.WriteLog("Worker1 cancelled in Delay()");
                break;                    
            }
            
            if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                Program.WriteLog("Doing work in Worker1");
        }
    
        Program.WriteLog("Worker1 completed; clean up");
    }
}
```

and finally the driver:

```
class Program
{
    public static List<string> log = new List<string>();

    public static void WriteLog(string s)
    {
        lock (log) log.Add(s);
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteLog("Start");
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var service = new BackgroundService(cts);
        WriteLog("Call StartAsync()");
        await service.StartAsync(cts.Token);
        WriteLog("Wait 500ms");
        await Task.Delay(1500);
        WriteLog("Call StopAsync()");
        await service.StopAsync(cts.Token);
        WriteLog("Done");
        log.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here are the results when you cancel 500ms after starting the first run, and then 1500ms into the second run (via calling `StopAsync` with the token provided by `cts.Token`).
You'll note that no work got done in the first run and you got "one unit" of work done in the second.

| Run 1 | Run 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 500ms, then cancel | 1500ms, then cancel |
| [image: run 1 result] | [image: run 2 result] |

This makes sense; in the first you cancelled before the real work could begin, and in the second, you cancelled after 1 unit of work completed, but before the second unit.

Comment: Wow, best answer I ever got! This works like a charm. The most important change was to add tasks to the list with the async "syntax". Some real quick remarks based on your comment:
1. In my actual code I did pass the token to Task.Delay(), my mistake
2. Stiff figuring that one out
3. Task.WhenAll did not block because it was not awaited I guess, but it did not work like it should, that's for sure.
4. Great advice! I'll keep that in mind
5. I was trying to do async/await all the way down but only after your answer I figured out how to..

THANK you!

Comment: Hm, re your #3.. I actually missed that. Regardless, once you do get it blocking with await, moving it makes sense. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You have requested cancellation but you didn't wait long enough for the tasks to react to it.  I would specify a timeout so that a worker that refuses to cancel doesn't stall the process.

```
cts.Cancel();
Task.WaitAll(workersToRun.ToArray(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Comment: This was not the solution to my problem but it is a good remark so I've implemented this in the solution from Kit. Thanks!